# BASH: Using a continue in a for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, if-statement, continue

As this is for work, I am unable to show my real example; but will a dummy example to explain my issue.
I have a BASH script that runs the following command:

```
for name in $HOME/data/individual-*-lookup; do
    $name
done
```

However if name equals a certain attribute (e.g. John). I want the for loop to skip over this name. I have tried the following code; but it still seems to run all the options:

```
#! /bin/bash

for name in $HOME/data/individual-*-lookup; do  
    if ["$name" == "$HOME/data/individual-john-lookup"]; then
        continue
    fi
    $filename

done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### A few issues I fixed in your code:

- Line 3, missing quotes around `$HOME`, to prevent the value to be parsed as multiple words, if it contains characters of the `$IFS` environment variable.
  (See: [ShellCheck: SC2231](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2231)):

  ```
  for name in $HOME/data/individual-*-lookup; do
             ^     ^
             "$HOME"/data/individual-*-lookup
  ```
- Line 4, missing spaces inside the test brackets:

  ```
  if ["$name" == "$HOME/data/individual-john-lookup"]; then
      ^                                            ^
  ```
- Line 4, mixed single bracket `[ condition ]` POSIX syntax and `==` Bash string equality syntax

  ```
  if ["$name" == "$HOME/data/individual-john-lookup"]; then
     ^        ^^                                    ^
  ```
- Line 7, missing double quotes `"` around `$filename`

  ```
   $filename
  ^         ^
   "$filename"
  ```

#### Fixed refactored version:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

filename=() # Array of a command with its parameters

for name in "$HOME"/data/individual-*-lookup; do
  # Continue to next name if file is physically same,
  # regardless of path string syntax
  [[ $name -ef "$HOME/data/individual-john-lookup" ]] && continue
  filename=(: "$name") # Command and parameters ":" is a dummy for command name
  "${filename[@]}"     # Run the command with its parameters
done
```

Test the `-ef` comparison to check the file is physically the same rather than string equality, so if file path expands with slight syntax differences, it does not matter.

The `-ef` condition operator is a Bash feature:

> `FILE1` **`-ef`** `FILE2`  True if file1 is a hard link to file2.

Since there is only one statement after the test, the shorter `test && command` can be used, in-place of `if test; then; command; fi`

The `$filename` command call is replaced by a `"${filename[@]}"` array for much better flexibility into adding arguments dynamically.